# MySQL: Why is Foreign Key failing?

Tags: mysql, percona

Trying to insert a row into MySQL using phpMyAdmin, and it is failing my with error:

```
 #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`staging`.`user_profiles`, CONSTRAINT `fk_user_profiles_users` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Can't figure out why. I created the database design in MySQL Workbench and it was working on MySQL 5.7 in development and now won't work with Percona server 5.5. Where am I NOT looking??

[SQL Statement and Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMAxg.jpg)

[Foriegn key in phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1N9E.jpg)

This is the table structure I created in MySQL Workbench (dashes for obscuring client info =P):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `staging_-----------`.`users` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `staging_-----------`.`users` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `role` ENUM('admin', 'vet', 'client') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `staging_-----------`.`user_profiles` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `staging_-----------`.`user_profiles` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `address_one` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `address_two` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `age` INT NULL,
  `sex` ENUM('m', 'f') NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `state` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `zip` VARCHAR(6) NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `photo` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  INDEX `fk_user_profiles_users2_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_profiles_users`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `staging_-----------`.`users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I've been trying to get my working code working again for 2 days now, and no love. What could have gone wrong? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Trying to drop a master table while child/referencing table still exists?

Comment: Sorry, the SQL successfully drops/creates the tables. Just can't insert a row into 'user_profiles' using an existing id from 'users'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the value you are inserting exists in user_id exists in `staging_-----------`.`users`

Maybe this is the problem ....

Comment: The value does exist. The row values that exist in 'staging.----'.'users' are
id: 1
email: stuff@stuff.stuff
password: awdfesgr
role: admin

I would have added a screenshot of the 'users' table showing the successful row, but my reputation wouldn't allow it.

Comment: generate scripts of two tables, structure and data and upload zip to ftp and public link.

Comment: Thank you so much! I exported the tables and was about to zip them up after sifting through the code, and I noticed my 'users' table was using MyISAM and my 'user_profiles' table was using InnoDB. I changed those two things, and it works! Thank you so much for leading me to the solution, I've been trying all the tiny things in the world. I will accept this answer! *bows to master*